# async/await works with real data, but not with local test data

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

https://snack.expo.io/@haosmark/kw-companion2

in the file api.js, when I set debugMode to false on line 17, the app works without a hiccup. It fetches a list of players, rooms, and matches, however if I set it to debugMode false, the app is showing 0 players online, and duplicates active match on "hosted rooms" and "active games" tabs. How do I correctly simulate network request with fake data? The above is complete code, and the following is the function in question:

```
  export const fetchDataAsync = async () => {
  playerList = {};
  activeGames = {};
  stagingRooms = {};

  //console.log('fetching data')
  if (debugMode) {
    result = await mockDataSmall.cnc3kw;
  } else {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    result = (await response.json()).cnc3kw;
  }

  //console.log('here0')
  Object.keys(result.users).map(parsePlayers);
  result.games.playing.map(parseRooms(ACTIVE_MATCH));
  result.games.staging.map(parseRooms(STAGING_ROOM));

  //console.log('here1')
  if (debugMode) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('success');
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
  //console.log('here2')
  return { playerList, activeGames, stagingRooms };
};
```

fakeData is in the same format as the live data, but a smaller sample

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). `await mockDataSmall.cnc3kw` should work just fine. When you `await someNonPromiseValue`, you effectively do `await Promise.resolve(someNonPromiseValue)`, so it's still async. This suggests your code is sensitive to *how long* the fetch takes.

Comment: Side note: `fetchDataAsync` is assigning to a **lot** of variables declared (one hopes) outside of it. That's generally not best practice, and could relate to the problem if it is a timing issue (see above).